# C++ GET Method Unhandled exception error performing mathematical operation

Tags: c++, cgi

Can anyone help me? I'm getting an unhandled exception error "Unhandled exception at 0x1027d440 (msvcr100d.dll) in program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000." Right now the program isn't actually performing any of the operations. All the answers come back as though the user selected the first radio button (I have 5 set up to choose which method to use). But the answer is always comes back as zero? What do I have to change to get it so if user chooses say.. subtraction then the program does that? I have it set to the values, but I guess there is an error somewhere. Thanks!

This is how I set it up on the HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//SoftQuad Software//DTD HoTMetaL PRO 6.0::19990601::extensions to HTML 4.0//EN" "hmpro6.dtd">
<HTML> 
  <HEAD> 
     <TITLE>Calculations</TITLE> 
  </HEAD> 
  <BODY> 

<P>
<p align="center">
<td>Select which Mathmatical operation you would like to perform:</td>
<BR> </P> 

<table border="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td>Enter a number to be calculated:</td>
<td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Number1" SIZE="14" MAXLENGTH="20"></p></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Enter a second number to be calculated:</td>
<td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Number2" SIZE="14" MAXLENGTH="20"></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>

     <FORM ACTION="http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/calc.exe" METHOD=”GET">

<p align="center">
 <INPUT TYPE = "RADIO" NAME = "mathOperation" VALUE = "0" ><b>Addition</B>
<BR>
 <INPUT TYPE = "RADIO" NAME = "mathOperation" VALUE = "1" ><b> Subtraction</B>
<BR>
  <INPUT TYPE = "RADIO" NAME = "mathOperation" VALUE = "2" ><b> Multiplication</B>
<BR>
  <INPUT TYPE = "RADIO" NAME = "mathOperation" VALUE = "3" ><b> Division</B>
<BR>
  <INPUT TYPE = "RADIO" NAME = "mathOperation" VALUE = "4" ><b> Square Root</B>
<BR>
</TR>
</table>

<p align="center">Enter the number of decimal places you'd like displayed: 
                <input TYPE="text" NAME="Decimal" size="14" MAXLENGTH="50">

        <P ALIGN="CENTER"><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="Submit1" CHECKED="CHECKED"
          VALUE="Submit Information"> </P> 
        <P ALIGN="CENTER"><INPUT TYPE="RESET" NAME="Reset1"
          VALUE="Reset Form"></P></FORM> </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//Function prototype

int getvar(char *, char *, char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

     int length;        // only up to 32767 chars
     char buffer[1024]; // Buffer size
     char *data;        // Input to program pointer

     char dest1[10];    // Destination fields
     char dest2[10];
     char dest3[10];

     float number1;     // first number 
     float number2;     // second number
     int mathOperation; // operation to perform
     float answer;      // place to store the result


     // GET Method
     if (strcmp(getenv("REQUEST_METHOD"), "GET") == 0)
     {
          // CGI input is located in the QUERY_STRING environment variable
          strcpy( buffer, getenv("QUERY_STRING"));
     }
     else
     {
          // CGI input data is read from standard input
          length=atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
          data= (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(length+1));
          cin.get(data, length);
          strcpy(buffer, data);
          free (data);
     }

     //   Find the program inputs in the user supplied data 

     getvar("Number1",       dest1,buffer);
     getvar("Number2",       dest2,buffer);
     getvar("MathOperation", dest3,buffer);


     //   Convert the data to the right data type

     number1 = (float) atof(dest1);    // The variable number1 contains the first number
     number2 = (float) atof(dest2);    // The variable number2 contains the second number

     mathOperation = atoi(dest3); // The math operation code

     //   Perform the correct mathematical operation based on the
     //   user specifications

     if(mathOperation == 0) // perform addition
     {
          answer = number1 + number2;
          cout << "<p/>\n" "Your addition answer is = " <<(answer)<< "<br/>\n";
     }
     else if (mathOperation == 1) // perform subtraction
     {
          answer = number1 - number2;
          cout << "<p/>\n" "Your subtraction answer is = " <<(answer)<< "<br/>\n";
     }
       else if (mathOperation == 2) // perform multiplication
     {
          answer = number1 * number2;
          cout << "<p/>\n" "Your answer is = " <<(answer)<< "<br/>\n";
     }
       else if (mathOperation == 3) // perform division
     {
          answer = number1 / number2;
          cout << "<p/>\n" "Your answer is = " <<(answer)<< "<br/>\n";
     }
         else if (mathOperation == 4) // perform square root
     {
          cout << "The square root of " << number1 << " is " << sqrt(number1) << endl;
          cout << "The square root of " << number2 << " is " << sqrt(number2) << endl;
     }
     else
     {

     // I still need to add additional code.. but.. for now..

     }

     cout << "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
     cout << "<html><body>\n";


     cout << "</body></html>\n";
     return 1;
} 
//(Include the c++ getvar comment block and code here)

    int getvar(char *var, char *dest, char *stream)
    {  
        char *vptr;
        int size, i=0, j=0, hex; /* ptr+i to src, ptr+j to dest */ 

        vptr=strstr(stream, var);  

        if(vptr) ; 
        else return(1); /* 1 for a checkbox thats off */

        if((vptr==stream)||(*(vptr-1)=='&')) ; 
        else return(-1); /* -1 for a var that appears in error */

        size=(int) strlen(var)+1; /* +1 accounts for the = */

        while(*(vptr+size+i)!='&') 
        {      
                if(*(vptr+size+i)=='+') /* output a space */           
                    *(dest+j)=' ';     
                else if(*(vptr+size+i)=='%') /* hex character */           
                        {              
                            sscanf(vptr+size+i+1,"%2x",&hex);              
                            *(dest+j)=(char)hex;               
                            i+=2;          
                        }      
            else *(dest+j)=*(vptr+size+i);     
                i++; j++;  
            }  
        *(dest+j)='\0';
            return(0);
    }
```

Comment: Use debugger, imitate environment as if program has been called by server and look which line causes error.

Comment: The error comes from dereferencing a null pointer. Typically, that is the result of sloppy error checking, like e.g. the call to malloc(), which you neglected to check.

Comment: @doomster I have been messing around with the code but am still getting an error. It opens up 'strcmp.asm' and highlights this line "mov     eax,[edx]". I really am totally lost as to how to proceed.

Comment: It seems to me you are using visual c++. They have debugger built-in, do they not?

Comment: UPPERCASE HTML!!?? IT BURNS!!

Comment: Well, as I said, start checking any return value for errors, like the mentioned `malloc()`, but also `sscanf()` and `getenv()` and generally everything where an error can be indicated by the returnvalue. Also, please format your code consistently.

Answer (score 1):

i think the thing is clear:

getenv("REQUEST_METHOD") returns a NULL-Pointer and strcmp tries to read it.
you should programmatically check if the environment variable does exist.

Comment: you're right, it has to do with that chunk of code. If I remove that chunk I don't get the error anymore. But my program REFUSES to do any math problem properly?? What am I missing to differentiate which radio option the user chooses? And why is every answer coming back as '0'?

Comment: may be your environment is not correct? does getvar works correctly? I assume that it shoul return the url encoded parameter. but we have no idea why it takes 3 parameter.

Comment: I have no idea if it is working properly. I feel like I'm really close with this code and changing a small thing here or there will get this working, but I don't have the knowledge to see what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: @MartyHuggins but how can you expect to get anything working if you "remove that chunk I". You have to ensure that your env-variables `"REQUEST_METHOD"` and `"QUERY_STRING"` are set. if they are unset then eventually the mechanism how to get those informations is another. may be you should read the manual of your webserver how these informations are delivered to applications.

Comment: @MartyHuggins if you are sure that this variables should be set then post your complete html-form. You also may use a debugger. Split up the problem: 1) how does the server deilver the data? 2) debug processing of that data. chtuluh guessed that you use MS VS if so then debug the application by manually set the environmentel variables in the debugging options to values that you expect to get from Server and run your program

Comment: I posted my complete html form. I have test the program and number1 and number2 both are not being pulled properly into the program. So every answer comes back as 0, as number1 and number2 do not have any values. I have no idea how to change this. Please help a rookie programmer! Sorry to be taking up your time but I appreciate the help

Comment: I figured out how to select the right radio button.. but the answer is not being returned properly still